# Транслятор языка программирования

Tags: java

Доброе утро !

Просьба навести на мысли как писать транслятор собственного языка на Java(SE).

Операторы простые if,for,типы переменных.

Готовый исходник не нужен, как должно выглядить в теорий или что то еще вот что нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В теории это выглядит так:

1. Задаемся генератором парсера/компилятора - для Java это [CUP](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/), [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), [JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net/) и проч. - гугль в помощь.
2. Задаемся грамматикой своего "языка" - у каждого [компилятора компилятора](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler) более-менее свой синтаксис - в основе которого лежит т.н. Банаховы формы. Например на ANTLR это [выглядит примерно так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/antlr-is-there-a-simple-example)
3. Генерируем на таргет языке (в данном случае на Java) набор классов реализующих разбор вашей грамматики
4. Профит.

Answer (score 0):

недавно спрашивали об этом - [Синтаксический анализ формального языка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/258833/java-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0)